# What exactly is a core file and why is it useful?

Tags: c, unix, coredump

As the title says:

What exactly is a core file and why is it useful?

I know when one is generated by UNIX, and I know how to check for one.  I'm aware they're useful for debugging... but I'm not entirely sure what it contains so I'm not sure why its useful!

Comment: It's basically a dump of a process' memory space at the moment it crashed and includes both code and data. You can feed the core file to a debugger and poke around the innards of the process to see what state thing were in, and hopefully figure out what caused the dump.

Comment: @Marc, that should really be posted as an answer :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=core+file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A core file is, essentially, a dump of the memory and registers of the program at the time that it crashed. When viewed in a debugger, you can get information on where the program was at the time of the crash, as well as getting stack traces or viewing the state of heap memory. Basically it lets you do anything you could with a debugger attached at the time of the crash, short of actually running code.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a snapshot of a process's memory.

It's usually created automatically when process ends abnormally (e.g. segmentation fault).

It can be loaded by debugging tools like `gdb` to try to determine the cause of the crash. For example, one can examine what the process was executing at the time of the failure, the values the variables had, the stack backtrace (the function that called the function that had the problem, the function that called it, and so on), etc.

Answer (score 1):

It basically contains the memory of the process and allows you to see/understand what caused the problem (stacktrace, examine variables etc.) For more details see [man core](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

A core file basically contain a copy of the process' memory map, and the values of the registers, including the IP (program counter). This is very useful for debugging, as a debugger can show you the actual state (variables, data sections, etc., and call stack) if you included debugging symbols when compiled the original program.

Answer (score 0):

core files contain the state of memory at the time they are created.  The are created on *nix systems when a program crashes (size can be limited by the OS property coredumpsize) or when the program receives a kill signal that tells it to core dump.

They especially useful when combined with an executable that has been complied with debug info as they can be read by debuggers help determine what went wrong.  With debuggers, you can see the stack trace that lead up to the crash and examine the state of variables in the corresponding stack frames.